# Update lookup field on child when apex trigger creates parent record

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a trigger (before insert, after insert) on the child of a lookup relationship. When a child is created the trigger looks to see if there is a parent record that has the same campaign name. If a parent record exists the id is added to the loopup field on the child. If a parent record doesn't exists then a new parent record is created.

The issue is that when a new parent is created the lookup field isn't updated with the new record id.

I'm hoping someone could help point me in the right direction for handling this.

I've tried to break the update of the child record and the creation of the new record into two sections. `

```
if(trigger.isBefore){
         if(trigger.IsInsert || trigger.isUpdate){
                     //do update loop
        }
     }else{
         //do insert loop for parent record
   }
}
```

Here is the trigger without the Trigger.isBefore

```
trigger EmailSummaryCreate on wbsendit__Campaign_Activity__c (before insert, 
before update, after insert) {

//    List of summary records that needs to be created 
List<CMRules__Email_Tracking_Summary__c> SummaryToInsert = new 
List<CMRules__Email_Tracking_Summary__c>();
//    List to update the tracking summary lookup field on the history record 
List<wbsendit__Campaign_Activity__c> historyFieldtoUpdate = new 
List<wbsendit__Campaign_Activity__c>();
//    List to hold all activity records in current context

//    set for only the campaign names in the current context
set<string> uKeyHistory = new set<string>();
for(wbsendit__Campaign_Activity__c hKey : trigger.new){
   if(hKey.CMRules__Unique_Key__c != null){
       uKeyHistory.add(hKey.CMRules__Unique_Key__c);
       }
 }
 Map<String,CMRules__Email_Tracking_Summary__c> matchingHistMap = new 
 Map<String,CMRules__Email_Tracking_Summary__c>();
 for(CMRules__Email_Tracking_Summary__c sum : [SELECT Id, 
 CMRules__Unique_Key__c FROM CMRules__Email_Tracking_Summary__c where 
 CMRules__Unique_Key__c IN :uKeyHistory]){
   matchingHistMap.put(sum.CMRules__Unique_Key__c, sum);
  } 



    for(wbsendit__Campaign_Activity__c h : trigger.new){

        if(matchingHistMap.containsKey(h.CMRules__Unique_Key__c)){
            //   set the tracking summary Id to the tracking summary record 
when matched 
            h.CMRules__Email_Tracking_Summary__c = 
matchingHistMap.get(h.CMRules__Unique_Key__c).Id;
                historyFieldtoUpdate.add(h);

            }else {             
                //create new summary record
                CMRules__Email_Tracking_Summary__c s = new 
 CMRules__Email_Tracking_Summary__c();              
                s.CMRules__Campaign_Name__c = h.name;
                s.CMRules__Contact__c = h.wbsendit__Contact__c;
                    SummaryToInsert.add(s);
            }
    }
       insert SummaryToInsert;

  }
```

Comment: can you add the code you have written to check for parent and create them as well?

Comment: Is this a hierarchical lookup, ie, from and to the same SObject?

Comment: @sanketkumar I added the code that works to add, and update the child record (wbsendit__Campaign_Activity__c ) and will create a new parent if it doesn't find a match.

Comment: @ThomasTaylor it is it is from a record on wbsendit__Campaign_Activity__c object to a record on CMRules__Email_Tracking_Summary__c object

Comment: You need to go back through your `SummaryToInsert` list after inserting it, and update the relevant `wbsendit__Campaign_Activity__c.CMRules__Email_Tracking_Summary__c` field. Is it possible that there would be duplicate values of `wbsendit__Campaign_Activity__c.CMRules__Unique_Key__c` for the records in the trigger?

Comment: @ThomasTaylor There would be duplicates of the unique key. It is a combination of the campaign field and the contact id. Whenever there is a an email sent a trigger from a managed package creates a history record and includes the contact, campaign name, activity (open, click etc.)

I was given the requirement for that to create the summary or update the activity record lookup field.